# Problems with ggpairs()- function

Tags: r

I am running R 4.0.3 within RStudio on my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to use the `ggpairs()` function out of the GGally library and some parts of the plot can't be displayed. The value of the correlation shows strange artefacts instead of values (see picture).

I tried this with the same R version and RStudio on different operating systems (Windows 10, popOS 20.04, Linux mint 20) with no problems, so I think this must have something to do with Ubuntu 20.04. Hopefully someone faced something similar and can provide some help.
[image]

Comment: For some reason it's not using a font which contains any ASCII characters.  Those are the missing character symbols for the text "Corr:0.807***".  So it's a font configuration or installation issue somewhere.